# Hardhat is not compiling

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have been trying to test out hardhat. I follow the guide on https://hardhat.org/getting-started/#quick-start. I use the sample project as mentioned. When I try to compile with `npx hardhat compile` nothing ever gets compiled (Nothing to compile). Also artifact folder never gets created. I tried it also with different projects, inside power shell and also visual studio code and the code is never compiling. Is there something I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

npm install glob@7.2.0
Try this it is Working for me

Comment: I was facing same issue, after installing glob it's compiling now

Answer (score 1):

Just downgrade the version of hardhat to 2.9.3 and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether the issue is still open, but you might want to try and run
`hardhat clean`
I had a similar issue with new solidity contracts not being detected and compiled, a clean solved the problem

Comment: This did the trick for me, unlike the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, I found a fix that works for now `npm install glob@7.2.0`. Hopefully future releases fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can change the version of the compiler (in both `contracts` and `hardhat.config.js` ) it worked for me. hopefully, it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might not have any contracts in your contracts folder: Check if you have any contract files in the contracts folder of your project. If there are no contracts, then there will be no artifacts generated.
and if you have contracts folder, rename it to "contracts" instead "contract"